# FPDF ¿Como elimino la linea blanca que se genera en una multicell con 2 linea que tiene un SetFillColor(), y que se muestra sólo en el pdf?

Tags: php, fpdf

Estoy utilizando la libreria FPDF para generar pdfs. Cuando el pdf se abre en el navegador está todo correcto pero cuando se abre el pdf con otra aplicación se muestra una delgada linea blanca que estropea el 'relleno' de color que he aplicado en la multicell. Alguien sabe a que se debe y como solucionarlo?

```
    $y0 = $pdf->GetY();
    if($y0 > 200){
      $pdf->AddPage();
      $y0 = $pdf->GetY();
    }
    $pdf->SetXY(20, $y0);
    $pdf->SetFillColor(85,136,156);
    
    $pdf->MultiCell(135, 7, mb_convert_encoding($modulo->nombreModulo, 'ISO-8859-1'),1,'L',1);
    $y1 = $pdf->GetY();

    if($y1<$y0) {
      $y0 = 50; 
    }
   
  
    $pdf->Rect(155,$y0,195-155,$y1-$y0, 'FD'); 
    $pdf->SetXY(155,$y0 +(($y1-$y0 -7)/2.1)); 
    $pdf->MultiCell(40, 7, mb_convert_encoding(conversionNota($notas_modulos[$modulo->id]) . ' ' . $notas_modulos[$modulo->id], 'ISO-8859-1'),0,'L',0);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba colocando estas instrucciones antes del `$pdf->Rect()`:

```
$pdf->SetDrawColor(85,136,156);
$pdf->SetLineWidth(0.4);
$pdf->Line(21,$y0+7,133,$y0+7);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(0,0,0);
```

Básicamente trazan una línea de grosor 0.4 mm sobre la línea que te molesta. Juega con el resto de parámetros para ajustarla lo mejor posible.

Comment: Muchas gracias David! era justo lo que necesitaba. Lo he añadido justo antes del multicell de nombre modulo que era donde necesitaba aplicar ese ajuste.

Comment: Estupendo. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)